# Query with condition on Count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, group-by, count

I am trying to make a query to my 'History' table and group results by a 'TypeId'

I have a column with the number of the registries found on each group (counter), to count how many registries there are, but I want to count only 1 if TypeId = 288 is found more than one time

Here is my query:

```
SELECT h.TypeId, t.Description, count(*) as Counter
FROM Hystory h
INNER JOIN HistoryType t on h.TypeId = t.Id
WHERE h.Code in (-- here list of codes)
GROUP BY h.TypeId
```

How can I make the condition to only count 1 on that case?

```
History:
Id  | TypeId | Code | Date      
1   | 23     | 2222 | xxxx
2   | 233    | 2222 | xxxx
3   | 288    | 2222 | xxxx
4   | 288    | 2222 | xxxx
5   | 23     | 2222 | xxxx
..

HistoryType:
Id  | Description
23  | User add file
233 | User modify file
288 | User access file
..
```

So, for a query for code = 2222 I want to get:

```
TypeId | Description     | Counter
23     | User add file   | 2
233    | User edit file  | 1
288    | User access file| 1
```

Comment: Help us help you - please post the table's structure, some sample data and the result you'd like to get for this sample.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: That query seems false... how does it let you group just by TypeId, having also the Date and Description fields declared in select?

Comment: @Mureinki More info added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT h.Id, h.Date, t.Description,
       ( SUM(CASE WHEN h.TypeId <> 288 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
         MAX(CASE WHEN h.TypeId = 288 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)            
       ) as Counter
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(A.Counter), A.id FROM(

    SELECT h.Id, count(h.Id) as Counter
    FROM #test_history1 h
    INNER JOIN #test_history2 t on h.TypeId = t.Id
    WHERE h.Code != 288
    GROUP BY h.TypeId, h.Id

    union
    SELECT h.Id, 1 as Counter
    FROM #test_history1 h
    INNER JOIN #test_history2 t on h.TypeId = t.Id
    WHERE h.Code = 288
    GROUP BY h.TypeId, h.Id
    )A
    GROUP BY A.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
select htyp.Id as TypeId, htyp.Description, 
       (case when htyp.Id = 288 then h.Counter1 else h.Counter end) as Counter
from HistoryType htyp cross apply 
    ( select count(*) as Counter, count(distinct h.TypeId) as Counter1
      from History h
      where h.TypeId = htyp.Id
    ) h;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ha.typeid,hs.Descr,ha.Counter from (select typeid,count (typeid) Counter  from history group by typeid) as ha
inner join 
(select descr,id from #historytype) as hs on ha.typeid = hs.id
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it lacks explanation. Please consider adding text to explain what it does, and why it answers the question posed.